# Linq expression to a Dbset argument doesnt work

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

x.CityID is invalid, how do i write lambda expression?

```
    private void adressComboBoxFill<T>(MetroComboBox varComboBox, System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> dbSet, string place) where T : class
    {
        if (place == "City"){
            varComboBox.DataSource = dbSet.ToList();
        } 
        else if (place == "District"){
            var type = dbSet.GetType();
            varComboBox.DataSource = dbSet.Where(x => x.CityID == selectedCity.CityID).ToList();
        }

        varComboBox.DisplayMember = place + "Name";
        varComboBox.ValueMember = place + "ID";
    }
```

Comment: You need to pass the EntityList. Why you `var type = dbSet.GetType();` do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line as

```
varComboBox.DataSource = dbSet.Cities.Where(x => x.CityID == selectedCity.CityID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid because you are passing in DBSet T a generic parameter. It knows nothing of City.

You need to make it non-generic, eg 
DBSet of Cities or whatever.